# Optaplanner:Add Dynamic visits without changing the already created visits

Tags: optaplanner

I am saving the best solution into the DB, and we display that on the web page. I am looking for some solution where a user can add more visits, but that should not change already published trips.

I have checked the documentation and found `ProblemFactChange` can be used, but only when the solver is already running.
In my case solver is already terminated and the solution is also published. Now I want to add more visits to the vehicle without modifying the existing visits of the Vehicle. Is this possible with Optaplanner?  if yes any example of documentation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PlanningPin annotation for avoiding unwanted changes.

[Optaplanner - Pinned planning entities](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.0.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#pinnedPlanningEntities)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking for pinning (see Ismail's excellent answer), take a look at the [OptaPlanner School Timetabling](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/quarkus-school-timetabling) example, which allows adding lessons between solver runs. The lessons simply get stored in the database and then get loaded when the solver starts.

The difficulty with VRP is the chained model complexity (we're working on an alternative): If you add a visit X between A and B, then make sure that afterwards A.next = X, B.previous = X, X.previous = A, X.next = B and X.vehicle = A.vehicle. Not the mention the arrival times etc.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to resolve what is left after the changes have been introduced. Let's say you are you visited half of your destinations (A -> B -> C)  but not yet (C - > D -> E) when two new possible destinations (D' and E') are introduced. Would not this be the same thing as you are starting in C and trying plan for D, D', E and E'? The solution needs to be updated on the progress though so the remainder + changes can be input to the next solution.

Just my two cent.